# XAML UWP Adaptive Buttons

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am trying to implement two side-by-side responsive buttons and I want them to behave like on the image below.

[image: ScreenCapture]

This is my XAML:

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="contentPanel">
       <Button x:Name="submitButton" Content="Submit"
                Margin="0,40,0,0"
                MinWidth="250"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>

        <Button x:Name="annulerButton" Content="Cancel"
                Margin="5,40,0,0"
                MinWidth="250"
                RelativePanel.RightOf="submitButton"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
<RelativePanel/>
```

Please, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Grid` with `ColumnDefinition` something like below.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="submitButton" Content="Submit" Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button x:Name="annuleButton" Content="Cancel" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

and end output will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open-source implementation of the [UniformGrid](https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control) for UWP instead of the relative panel.

Alternatively, you can try to put your buttons into the standard Grid control, though it may misbehave if resized to a rather small size. But as the buttons' minimal width is set to the same value in your case, you will not face this issue.

```
<Grid x:Name="contentPanel">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Button x:Name="submitButton" Content="Submit"
            Margin="0,40,0,0"
            MinWidth="250"
            Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Button x:Name="annulerButton" Content="Cancel"
            Margin="5,40,0,0"
            MinWidth="250"
            Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```